# htaccess wildcard redirect with an exception

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I'm currently using below redirect rules.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domainexample.co.uk [OR]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domainexmaple.co.uk

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://domainexamplenew.com/$1
```

I'd like to add an exception in. For a GSC html verification file e.g. googlee08e8ab5c95d7b8d.html - just can't get it work

Any help/suggestions are appreciated,

John

Answer (score -1):

There is like you have infinite loop in redirects.

You should use same domain name in conditions and in rule.

Now when user open page on domainexamplenew.com then it redirect to domainexamplenew.com and again and again.

If you want redirect from domainexamplenew.co.uk to domainexamplenew.com then you should change domain in conditions.

For example

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domainexample.com [OR]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domainexmaple.com

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://domainexamplenew.com/$1
```

Comment: It's not a loop if the htaccess with those rules are only located on one of the websites